# .bat %server% wildcard access a server share

Tags: batch-file, cmd, share

we are writing a .bat script that will navigate to a server share, and we intend to do this for a few different networks. The share will remain the same however the server will always be changing due to different customer networks. We need the wild card to be used in a similar way to that %username% or %domain% are used. As we have more than a few networks and server names to attend to this script needs to be very generalized.

Anyhelp would be appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "We need the wild card to be used in a similar way to..."  Did you maybe mean system variables or user supplied variables?

Comment: thanks for the comment if there is one i would like a system variable other wise a method in which i can get the server and use that

Comment: ok have the answer the system variable is %LOGONSEVER% = Local Returns the name of the domain controller that validated the current logon session. thanks for the help

Comment: Good, glad you found your answer.  If you didn't know, you can easily see a list of all the environmental variables by just typing `set` in the command prompt.  If the need arises for user input, just use `set /p someVariable=What to prompt the user:`

Answer (score 0):

ok have the answer the system variable is %LOGONSEVER% = Local Returns the name of the domain controller that validated the current logon session. thanks for the help